# How to send strings as signals to circom?

Tags: circom

I want to create a circuit to measure the length of a string in Circom.
There are only numeric data types, how can I do that?

Comment: why is tag as tag:rust?

Comment: How do you have 15.4k rep and don't know better than to ask a question that isn't reproducible, and doesn't provide debugging information?

Comment: it's a perfect question. not sure what you guys are not happy about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply string as a series of bytes. You can:

- Make your circuit take in an array of signals of length 256
- Iterate over the array
- Look for first 0 byte
- Save the index as string length

This will allow you to measure string lengths of up to 256 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to an array of numbers (bytes) using an encoding appropriate to your use case, e.g. Unicode or ASCII.